# How to add a pause between sending messages in python telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sleep, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm making a bot with [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) that sends you several messages in a row in response to a single command. When all messages arrive at once, it is inconvenient to the user. I want to add a pause between sending and send `action=ChatAction.TYPING` between them. Is there any convenient way to do this without using something like `time.sleep()`?

Comment: Please explain why `sleep` is undesirable.

Comment: @Prune as I understand it, 'sleep' will stop the whole bot working for all users. Or is it not and I can safely use sleep?

Comment: perhaps a for loop which does nothing?

Comment: @Dudnikov For multiple instances you should probably use threading. Then sleep will not be an issue. Either that or perform a function where you know how long it takes to calculate and repeat that as many times as you need (bit hacky though)

Comment: @JustCurious I think this decision will be even worse than stopping the entire program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the framework's [JobQueue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) solves your problem. It allows you to schedule messages to be sent at some point in the future.

Quote:

*You can also add a job that will be executed only once, with a delay:*

```
>>> def callback_30(bot, job):
...     bot.send_message(chat_id='@examplechannel', 
...                      text='A single message with 30s delay')
...
>>> j.run_once(callback_30, 30)
```

*In thirty seconds you should receive the message from callback_30.*